# how can I handle the leaderboard response in swift 4

Tags: swift, leaderboard

I am writing a game in swift and want to use a leaderboard in gamecenter. The code to get the leaderboard score is called from viewdidLoad() method on my main screen.
The problem I have is that fetching the score is done in the background. That's the reason I store them in Userdefaults to be able to access them any time.
Nevertheless it takes too long to get them loaded from GameCenter. 
So if a user opens the game and directly starts to play the game the displayed highscore is 0.
If he waits for a few seconds before starting to play the correct highscore is displayed.
Any ideas what I can do?
Below the code I am using:

```
func getHighscore(){
    let leaderBoard: GKLeaderboard = GKLeaderboard()
    leaderBoard.identifier = "MemojiHighscore"
    leaderBoard.timeScope = .allTime
    leaderBoard.loadScores { (scores, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("can not load highscore")
    } else {
        guard let scores = scores else {return}
        for score in scores {
            if score.value > UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highScoreFriends") {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(numericCast(score.value), forKey: "highScoreFriends")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should store the user's latest score in userdefaults and read it from there to show on startup. In the background you can post the user score to leaderboard. Only on first launch when you don't have score in userdefaults, you should put a loader to fetch the score from leaderboard.

Comment: Also if you set range for this query(`leaderBoard.range = NSMakeRange(0, 1)`), it might improve the load time.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But what cam I do to get  the best of allfriends Highscore at startup?